# Pandas sort a subset of column based on conditions

Tags: python, pandas

Let's say I have the dataframe:

```
c1 c2
a1 9
a1 11
a1 12
a1 8
a2 10
a2 14
a2 6
```

I would like to sort only subset `a2` of column `c1`:

```
c1|c2
a2 6 <=
a1 9
a2 10 <=
a1 11
a1 12
a2 14 <=
a1 8
```

Here the traditional sorting with `sort_values` doesn't seem to work.
Also, c2 is composed of only unique values, so there is no possibility to have repeated values.

Comment: I don't think your problem is well defined, it is not clear what rules govern how values are sorted and how.

Comment: @cs95 reorder 'c2' values belonging to group 'c1' == 'a2' in function of 'c2' values belonging to group 'c1' == 'a1'. To place them in the nearest 'c2' value.

Answer (score 0):

Lets say your dataframe is in `df`

```
df = df[df['c1'] == 'a2']
```

Comment: Hi! while I want the subset df['c1'] == 'a2' to be sorted, I need exactly the second table as output.

Comment: @JoséVallejo - Your question  is little unclear. Let me ask you again, You want data where `c1` contains only `a2` or its inverse

Comment: I'm sorry if not well explained, I want 'c2' values belonging to group 'c1'  == 'a2' find their order place on the 'c2' column. The ordering concerns only this group.

Comment: You mean you are need of index values of those sorted records, like this - https://pasteboard.co/Jih0m0x.png